# Is it possible to open more than one query tab without opening another connection via Alias in Squirrel SQL?

Tags: squirrel-sql

I keep commenting out my queries in the SquirreL SQL client, but I also have been opening new connections using other Aliases, however it all gets a bit crowded in the tab area.

I've also been able to save my queries in files, which works great except for the fact that the entire path to the file (often very long) appears in the tab.

Is it possible to just have another SQL tab opened, or might there be a way to simplify how many SQL query tabs I open?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope, the answer will be still useful, although the question is asked some times ago :-)

> Is it possible to just have another SQL tab opened, or might there be a way to simplify how many SQL query tabs I open?

You can open a new SQL-Worksheet for the current session.
Try one of the following:

- Shortcut CTRL+N
- Menu Session >> New SQL-Worksheet
- In the toolbar, the icon right of the rollback button.

> I've also been able to save my queries in files, which works great except for the fact that the entire path to the file (often very long) appears in the tab.

This changed in 3.4.0. Please see [the changes](http://squirrel-sql.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/squirrel-sql/trunk/sql12/doc/src/main/resources/changes.txt)

*Instead of displaying the file paths in Session tabs a small button is displayed when an open file exists.
  Clicking the button will open a popup menu that gives access to several information and functions concerning the file.*

Comment: I noticed that you can rename the tab too if you right-click on them..that makes them shorter and more readable.